# What's the meaning of 龙舟队分哪个两个组？

Tags: grammar, meaning, separable-verbs

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> 龙舟队分哪个两个组？

Moreover, is 分组 a separable verb 离合动词, or is it a verb and a noun?

I haven't found grammar references that explain the verb in question. I'm confused because 哪 is in the middle of the supposed separable verb.

Comment: Where did you see the sentence?

Comment: In my chinese book easy steps to chinese 5.

Comment: From a passage about dragon boat racing?

Comment: @ANTXON Are you sure there isn't a typo?  It doesn't look quite right. Or any context?

Comment: 哪个两个 sounds like Southwestern Mandarin, not MSM.

Answer (score 4):

> 龙舟队分哪个两个组？

I think it is a typo.

remove the extra 个 and write **龙舟队分哪两个组?**(dragon boat teams divided into which two groups?) make the most sense

> 龙舟队分[哪两个组]?

> 龙舟队分[男子组和女子组]

> 龙舟队分[成人组和少年组]

> 龙舟队分[业余组和职业组]

It is wrong to use 个 (a) as a classifier for 两个组 (two groups)

Similarly:

你說的是哪兩个隊 (O)

你說的是哪兩隊 (O)

你說的是哪个隊 (O)

你說的是哪隊 (O)

你說的是哪个兩隊 (X)

你說的是哪个兩个隊 (X)(X)

Answer (score 1):

龙舟队    ---  (The) Dragon boat team

分        --- separated / grouped into

哪个        ---  which

两个       ---   two

组？       ---  groups?

Answer (score 1):

I think this sentence is not perfectly grammatical. You can analyze it as follows:

> 龙舟队 The Dragon Boat Team
>
> 分 (divide into, assign to)
>
> 哪个 which (one)
>
> 两个组 two groups

It doesn't sound grammatical to me mainly because 哪个 means "哪（一）个 which one", but the subsequent noun phrase is about "**两个组** two groups".

We can probably read it as "which two groups", but then the Chinese would be “哪两个组”.

As additional evidence, Googling the quoted “哪个两个组” phrase yields a good 5 results, against 84k for “哪两个组”.

Anyway, putting it all together it becomes something like:

> Which two groups is the Dragon Boat Team assigned to?

or

> Which two groups is the Dragon Boat Team divided into?

In both these cases, I think 分组 is **not** a separable verb. Why?

In a separable verb the separable part is the object of the sentence (that's why they are also called *verb-object phrases*) but this object has a non-specific meaning (some linguists call it *virtual* or *ostensive* object), and as such, in English it's often rendered as a [1-valency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_(linguistics)) verb. Compare:

> 我吃饭 = I eat <strike>food</strike>
>
> 我跑步 = I run <strike>steps</strike>

Instead your sentence already has an object — or if you prefer, the subject of a passive form —, which is 龙舟队 ...unless you want to argue that 龙舟队 is who performs the division in groups. (The fact that 龙舟队 is the topic of a topic-comment construction doesn't affect its grammatical role.)

As a counter-test, can you rewrite 组 in a **把 + Obj. + V** structure? You can't. Instead 龙舟队 can be placed after 把:

> 他**把龙舟队**分哪两个组 (ok) vs <strike>龙舟队把组分哪两个 (???)</strike> (not ok)

So what is 组 then? I think it's the object of a **3-valency result complement structure**. This is relatively easier to see if we rewrite the verb+result in a copy structure, instead of topic-comment. (This is similar to what you can do with degree complements):

> (主语) **分** 龙舟队 **分（成/到）** 哪两个组

This is my analysis. Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

分 often comes with 为：

她让学生每四人分为一小组。
She asked the students to split into groups of four.

Just thinking about a question yesterday on the origin of tense words in Chinese and whether the teams divide themselves or 被分为. Certainly, a team is a team and remains undivided.

龙舟队被分为哪两个组？
The dragon boat teams are divided into which two groups?

龙舟队分为哪两个组？
Dragon boat teams divide into which two groups?

But, if the team *is* divided after some fashion, my piercingly nautical suggestion would be:

比较胖的队员全部坐在右舷，瘦瘦的队员都坐在左舷。
Fat team members all sit on the starboard side, thin team members all sit on the port side.

Answer (score 0):

龙舟队分**哪个两个组**？ is simply incorrect.

The combination of 哪个 and 两个组 doesn't make any sense grammatically and logically.

哪个 means WHICH ONE, for example: A B C D, 哪个是B？(which one is B?). The second one is B.

哪两个组 is right, means WHICH TWO GROUPS?

So the correct sentence is 龙舟队分哪两个组？